# My bot written in python works, but I get a Runtime error when I exit the program. How do I fix this?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, bots, python-asyncio

Here is the code for my bot:

```
import discord
import response
from discord import message 
from discord import channel
from discord.errors import PrivilegedIntentsRequired
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import schedule
import datetime
import asyncio
import time

async def send_message(message, user_message, is_private):
    try:
        responses = response.responsehandle(user_message)
        print(responses)
        await message.channel.send(responses)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

async def poll_message(client):
    channel_id = 1234567890
    channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
    
    target_time = datetime.time(hour=8, minute=40)  # change the hour and minute as needed

    while not client_is_closed():
        now = datetime.datetime.now().time()
        if now == target_time:
            await channel.send('Test')
            break
        await asyncio.sleep(60) # wait 60 seconds before checking again  # wait 60 seconds before checking again


async def change_nickname(client, guild_id):
    # get the target member and new nickname
    
    poll_list = []
    members = []

    guild = client.get_guild(guild_id)

   
    for member in guild.members:
        members.append(member)
        poll_list.append(member.id)
        # or do whatever you wish with the member detail
    pinhead = 1234567890

    print(poll_list)
    integer = random.randint(0, 10)


    member_id = poll_list[integer]
    member = guild.get_member(member_id)
    new_nickname = 'New Nickname'

    # change the member's nickname
    #await member.edit(nick = new_nickname)
    #print(f'Changed {member.name}#{member.discriminator}\'s nickname to {new_nickname}.')



async def run_discord_bot():
    TOKEN = '1234567890wertyuiopasdfghjkl'
    client = discord.Client(intents = discord.Intents.all())
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents = discord.Intents.all())


    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print(f'{client.user} is now running!')
        guild_id = 1234567890
        await change_nickname(client, guild_id)

        await poll_message(client)

    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        if message.author == client.user:
            return 
        username = str(message.author)
        user_message = str(message.content)
        channel= str(message.channel)

        print(f"{username} said '{user_message}' ({channel})")
        if user_message[0] == '?': 
            user_message = user_message[1:]
            await send_message(message, user_message, is_private = True)
        else:
            await send_message(message, user_message, is_private = False)
       
        
    await client.start(TOKEN)
    
        
try:
    asyncio.run(run_discord_bot())
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Exiting...")
```

Everything runs correctly, but when I exit using ctrl + C, I receive the error: "RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'run_discord_bot' was never awaited
bot.run_discord_bot()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback"

Although this error does not seem to affect the functionality of the bot, I'd rather not see it. Sorry if my question is dumb, I am very new to writing discord bots and python in general.

I tried different techniques for 'run_discord_bot()' at the end of my code, but every time I tried I received errors for not properly awaiting. 'asyncio.run(run_discord_bot())' seems to be the only properly functioning variation I could find.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To increase your chances of receiving an answer and to improve the experience of everyone viewing your question I would strongly recommend you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In your question you just dumped all your code, 95% of which is completely irrelevant to the actual issue. You also failed to provide the complete error traceback. A minimal reproducible example helps you gain clarity on the issue and it helps other people to understand and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

That warning comes because you *don't* await `run_discord_bot`. You preemptively catch the `KeyboardInterrupt` *outside* the runner.

The `asyncio.run` function already registers a handler for `SIGINT` to call the `cancel` method on the main task. (The main task is created from whatever coroutine you pass to `asyncio.run`.)

That means, you can cleanly catch the `asyncio.CancelledError` inside that main task to do whatever cleanup you deem necessary. This is why I would recommend the pattern of **always** having a `main` function and do **everything** from there and in the global context **only ever** call `asyncio.run(main())`:

```py
from asyncio import CancelledError, run, sleep


async def stuff() -> None:
    print("Doing stuff...")
    await sleep(1000)


async def main() -> None:
    try:
        await stuff()
    except CancelledError:
        print("Exiting prematurely...")
        exit(1)
    print("Finished!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run(main())
```

Output when pressing `Ctrl+C` after a few seconds:

```
Doing stuff...
Exiting prematurely...
```

No warnings.